# Why does Python 2 allow comparisons between lists and numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently discovered a typo in my program

```
while len(first_list) > second_list:
    do_stuff
```

I played around with this and discovered that `5 < ["apple"] == True` and `5 > ["apple"] == False`

Why does Python allow these sorts of comparisons? What is being evaluated under the hood to determine that `5` is less than `["apple"]`?

Comment: Because Python 2 is broken by design, you should use Python 3 which will raise an exception if you try such comparison.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the types are compared in this case, so it's like writing:

```
type(5) < type(["apple"])
```

and since "int" and "list" are compared lexicographically ("i" < "l"), you're getting this output.

If you try:

```
"5" > ["apple"]
```

you'll get False, since "string" > "list".

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are **ordered by their type names**; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Comment: Any document or source code link demonstrating this will be helpful. Without that it is just a assumption

Comment: See this other question on SO: [How does Python compare string and int?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/2291710)

Comment: Not correct. `{}<0` evaluates to False, but `dictionary` comes before `int`

Comment: @yBot I added the link that I think justifies my assumption.

Comment: I don't see how this justifies your assumption. The quote only says objects of the same type are ordered by their addresses, says nothing about ordering different types using the type name lexicographically.

Comment: @yBot Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Comment: @yBot "Objects of different types **except** numbers [...]"

Comment: I still don't see how that explains it. That post is totally wrong as far as I can see, there's nothing in the official docs about this, only a CPython implementation detail.

Comment: This post is totally right except for the example with the number 5.

Answer (score 3):

Its from documentation of python 2:

> The operators `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, and `!=` compare the values of two objects. The objects need not have the same type. If both are numbers, they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but arbitrarily. You can control comparison behavior of objects of non-builtin types by defining a `__cmp__` method or rich comparison methods like `__gt__`.

Answer (score -3):

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), different types just have to compare unequal, it's up to the implementation to decide how to handle that. It just so happens that CPython's implementation decides to order based on type names.

Comment: Any specific reason for the down votes?

Comment: downvotes are probably because this answer doesn't really answer anything but just guesses... and actually, it's _not_ up to the implementation.

Comment: Care to explain? Where in the official docs does it define this?

Comment: see the other answers?

Comment: I did. Other answers along with their examples are all about CPython, nothing about the official language docs

Comment: ah, sorry... you're right. it's implementation dependent. but it must be deterministic. either way, your answer isn't all that helpful compared to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/214446 (btw, I didn't downvote)

Comment: Ah well, it was still a useful discussion that shouldn't get down voted. So much for wisdom of the masses I guess. Sigh.

Comment: I think you should link to Python 2 documentation when answering Python 2-specific question. It will at least explain the behavior of the code from the question.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Fixed the answer for what it's worth.